# Quoted string as optional argument to Python script

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I have simple utility script that I use to download files given a URL.  It's basically just a wrapper around the Linux binary "aria2c".

Here is the script named `getFile`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#
# SCRIPT NAME: getFile
# PURPOSE: Download a file using up to 20 concurrent connections.
#

import os
import sys 
import re
import subprocess

try:
    fileToGet = sys.argv[1]

    if os.path.exists(fileToGet) and not os.path.exists(fileToGet+'.aria2'):
        print 'Skipping already-retrieved file: ' + fileToGet
    else:
        print 'Downloading file: ' + fileToGet
        subprocess.Popen(["aria2c-1.8.0", "-s", "20", str(fileToGet), "--check-certificate=false"]).wait() # SSL

except IndexError:
    print 'You must enter a URI.'
```

So, for example, this command would download a file:

```
$ getFile http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Self-portrait_with_Felt_Hat_by_Vincent_van_Gogh.jpg
```

What I want to do is permit an optional second argument (after the URI) that is a quoted string.  This string will be the new filename of the downloaded file.  So, after the download finishes, the file is renamed according to the second argument.  Using the example above, I would like to be able to enter:

```
$ getFile http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Self-portrait_with_Felt_Hat_by_Vincent_van_Gogh.jpg "van-Gogh-painting.jpg"
```

But I don't know how to take a quoted string as an optional argument.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test the length of `sys.argv`; if it is more than 2 you have an extra argument:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    filename = sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: Oh, so if you pass a quoted string to Python, it will automatically treat it as a single argument?

Comment: Exactly; the quoting is a shell feature, nothing to do with Python, really.

Comment: Ahh, OK thank you.  I guess I did not practice due diligence on this question.  I should have at least tried it and see how the arguments worked, instead of assuming it wouldn't work as you describe.  :)  So, forgive my laziness -- and thanks very much!

Comment: Or use `argparse` ... :)

Answer (score 1):

The shell will pass it as a second argument (normally) if you provide spaces between them.

For example, here is `test.py`:

```
import sys

for i in sys.argv:
    print(i)
```

And here is the result:

```
$ python test.py url "folder_name"
test.py
url
folder_name
```

The quotes doesn't matter at all, as it's handled in the shell, not python. To get it, just take `sys.argv[2]`.

Hope this helps!